# Issues in function calling?

Tags: c#, function, arguments

I have a function at button onclick event as:

```
 protected void show()
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getconnectionstring());
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "paging_select";
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startrowindex", current_page_number);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maximumrows", page_size);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@totalrows", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            cmd.Parameters["@totalrows"].Direction =
                          ParameterDirection.Output;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);



            sda.Fill(dt);
            int totalRows = (int)cmd.Parameters["@totalrows"].Value;
            sda.Dispose();
            gridview.DataSource = dt;
            gridview.DataBind();
            con.Close();
           // Response.Write("Total rows=" + totalRows + "<br/>");


            //Response.Write("total pages will be" + totalpages_counter(totalRows).ToString() + "having 3 records per page" + "<br/>");
            label2.Text = current_page_number.ToString();
          //  label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Text = totalpages_counter(totalRows).ToString();
           // label3.Visible = false;
          //  Response.Write("Page" + " " + label2.Text + " " + "of" + " " + label3.Text);

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Response.Write(ee.Message);
        }

    }
```

Executing it giving a error.

> Error 1   No overload for 'show' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

I hope its because function has no argument.But my problem is that i want to execute this code in a function which mightn't have any argument i.e   **protected returntype funtionname().** it should be like this  because i have to call this function from somewhere else.
or better  you can tell me how to call a function which is of following type:

```
protected void show(Object sender,EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Could you please change the tag C to C# in order not to cause a confusion?

Comment: You can remove all the Db code, it is not relevant. And please describe a little better how you want to use this. With code.

Answer (score 1):

Just call your method from a click handler with the correct signature:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more answer to provide an alternative for dynamically created controls (or just events bound through code instead of designer).

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => show());
```

That would setup the simple event handler which would then just invoke your `show()` method.